# CakePHP / PHP Json decode a URL response

Tags: php, json, cakephp, twitter

For a URL I am trying to count it's tweets through this API request:

```
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk
```

This (in a Browser) returns the following Json:

```
{"count":216743,"url":"http:\/\/www.bbc.co.uk\/"}
```

I can manually parse the response:

```
$tweets = json_decode('{"count":216743,"url":"http:\/\/www.bbc.co.uk\/"}');
$this->set('tweets', $tweets->{'count'});
```

When I enter the URL instead of the Json, it doesn't request any data. How would I get the following to work?

```
$tweets = json_decode('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk');
$this->set('tweets', $tweets->{'count'});
```

Comment: Why do you think this would be possible or would make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json_decode` expects to get a JSON string. `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk` is not a JSON string, it's a URL. `json_decode` does not fetch URLs. You need to fetch the URL yourself, then pass the result to `json_decode`:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk');
$tweets = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `json_encode()` on the URL directly. Get the contents of the page first (using, e.g., `file_get_contents` - [docu link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)) and then try to decode it:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk');
$tweets = json_decode( $content );

// do your stuff
```